# How to use Timelinemax / Tween for moving object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween, gsap

Hi Awesome Stackoverflow fellas,

I tried to move my object in three.js to a certain point.
As far as I know, I need to use Tween.js.
But in the tutorial I watched it imported Tween Js but when he uses tween js he used 'timelinemax' which I think little bit not understandable? by the way.

My code is as below.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();





scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 )
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
camera.position.x = 40;
camera.position.y = 20;
camera.position.z = 1500;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var render = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera)
}
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
// end template here




var coord =[{"x":300,"y":10,"z":10},{"x":20,"y":30,"z":30},{"x":30,"y":0,"z":50},
            {"x":40,"y":20,"z":70},{"x":50,"y":100,"z":90},
            {"x":60,"y":30,"z":110},{"x":70,"y":150,"z":90}]


var sphr
var geom
var sphrinfo=[]

function drawsphre(){
    for (let i =0; i<coord.length; i++){

        var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { flatShading: true } )
        geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 60, 50, 50);
        sphr = new THREE.Mesh( geom, mat);
        console.log()

        sphr.position.set(coord[i].x,coord[i].y,coord[i].z)
        sphrinfo.push(sphr)

        sphr.tl = new TimelineMax()
        sphr.tl.to(sphr.position.set,.5,{x:100,y:204,z:300})


        scene.add(sphr);
        render()



    }
}
drawsphre();



function movesphr(){
for (let i=0;i<coord.length;i++){
    sphrinfo[i].z=10
}

}



function animate() {


}

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
scene.add( light );

// White directional light at 70% intensity shining from the top.
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.7 );
scene.add( directionalLight );
```

I put

TimelineMax
but the spheres doesn't move at all.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Eventually What I'm tyring to do is 
Generating a bunch of spheres having specific x,y,z values.
And making all the spheres drop to the plane which I guess where the z coordinates is Zero.

I'm trying to animate that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just to confirm, you are referring to [Tween.js](https://www.createjs.com/tweenjs) when you say tween? and you are meaning [GSAP](https://greensock.com/docs/) when you refer to Timeline?

Comment: I was referring tween.js but when i search tween.js the search result always indicates gsap and timeline. why is that? are those same thing?

Comment: no, not the same. Tween is just a general term for an animation be**tween** 2 values.

Comment: If so, when I import the function, I shouldn't type import Tween. right? but some examples imports 'Tween' in their code. That's why I was little confused. Some examples imports 'Timelinemax' some imports 'Tween' and the answer below imports 'gsap' why is that?

Comment: We highly recommend using [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3/)

Comment: @Soonik, in GSAP, a Tween if for a single animation, a Timeline is a collection of tweens. The is a massive amount of videos on the [gsap site](https://greensock.com/learning/) that explain it all.

Comment: @2pha, thank you so much GSAP looks super cool I just had a look. The amount of video on the website is bit overwhelming though, I feel like I definitely need to look into that.

Comment: @Soonk Start simple: with [the getting started article](https://greensock.com/get-started/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweens work on properties, but you are trying to tween `sphr.position.set` which is a function.
You should just tween the x, y and z values on `sphr.position`.

Below is a demo, check the `animateBox` function.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material;
init();
renderloop();
// Start the box animating.
animateBox();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 800;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function renderloop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderloop);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animateBox() {
  
  // just use tweens.
  //gsap.to(mesh.position, {x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) - 300), duration: 5, ease: "elastic"});
  //gsap.to(mesh.position, {y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) - 300), duration: 5, ease: "elastic"});
  //gsap.to(mesh.position, {z: Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) - 300), duration: 5, ease: "elastic"});
  
  // use a timeline (and call this function again on complete).
  // This uses GSAP V3
  var timeline = gsap.timeline({onComplete: animateBox});

  // animate mesh.position.x,
  // a random number between -300 and 300,
  // for 2 seconds.
  timeline.to(
    mesh.position,
    {x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) - 300), duration: 2, ease: "elastic"},
    0
  );
  
  // animate mesh.position.y
  timeline.to(
    mesh.position,
    {y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) - 300), duration: 2, ease: "elastic"},
    0
  );

  // animate mesh.position.z
  timeline.to(
    mesh.position,
    {z: Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) - 300), duration: 2, ease: "elastic"},
    0
  );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```